# Smarter CSS colour change

Tags: css

I'm building a site in a way that I can easily replace colours of multiple elements by making a couple of simple CSS changes. However, I've come up against a lack of knowledge when it comes to a particular element I'm working on:

**CSS**:

```
.et_pb_toggle_0.et_pb_toggle.et_pb_toggle_close {
background-color: rgba(225, 30, 30, 1) !important; /* REPLACE THIS COLOUR */
border-bottom-color: rgba(225, 30, 30, 1) !important; /* REPLACE THIS COLOUR */
border-left-color: rgba(225, 30, 30, 1) !important; /* REPLACE THIS COLOUR */
border-right-color: rgba(225, 30, 30, 1) !important; /* REPLACE THIS COLOUR */}
```

As all of these use the same colour, is there a smarter way to write this to combine them so I'm only replacing the colour once? I've tried to combine with commas, spaces, semi-colons and it just doesn't seem to work.

The reason I'm having to use for seperate border items is because this is to override existing CSS which defines that rather than just one border.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks, Ant.

Comment: welcom to SO, try using CSS preprocessor(SASS, LESS & etc) and define colors as global variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS variables

```
:root {
  --main-color: rgba(225, 30, 30, 1);
}
.et_pb_toggle_0.et_pb_toggle.et_pb_toggle_close {
background-color: var(--main-color) !important; 
border-bottom-color: var(--main-color) !important; 
border-left-color: var(--main-color) !important; 
border-right-color: var(--main-color) !important;
}
```

Here's a reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: It's worth pointing out the browser compatibility section at the bottom of that reference - Internet Explorer won't support this, which may be a problem depending on your audience.

Comment: That is truly beautiful and exactly the sort of thing that I needed. Thank you very much geeksamu. IE is a slight issue, but I've had a look around and it looks like I should just define a fallback colour for each item.